# Xamarin.forms new Media element not playing youtube video

Tags: asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I was implementing xamarin forms Media element. I'm able to play videos from the link provided in xamarin media element official doc. but the problem is i want to play youtube video but it isn't playing. I have set the flag in app.xaml.cs but still nothing happened for youtube videos. It only shows blank screen in both emulator and in physical device.

```
<MediaElement Source="https://youtu.be/E7Voso411Vs" x:Name="mediaSource"
                          AutoPlay="True" ShowsPlaybackControls="True" 
                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Hope to get solution.
Thank you.

Comment: That YT link is a web-based video player, not a direct video link. Use a `WebView` instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should extract url from youtube with `https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={VideoId}` first,try this:

```
<MediaElement  x:Name="mediaSource"
             AutoPlay="True" ShowsPlaybackControls="True" 
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

then in your page.cs:

```
public MediaElem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mediaSource.Source = GetYouTubeUrl("E7Voso411Vs");

    }



public string GetYouTubeUrl(string videoId)
    {
        var videoInfoUrl = $"https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={videoId}";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var videoPageContent = client.GetStringAsync(videoInfoUrl).Result;
            var videoParameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(videoPageContent);
            var encodedStreamsDelimited1 = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(videoParameters["player_response"]);
            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(encodedStreamsDelimited1);
            string url = (string)jObject["streamingData"]["formats"][0]["url"];
            return url;           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't wrapping HttpClient inside "using" block considered an anti-pattern ?

Comment: For this example, it's fine. If you were trying to get the URL for 50 youtube videos, then yeah, you probably wouldn't want to create a new HttpClient each time.

Comment: April 2022. This returns "One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 410 (Gone).)"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can not play it directly. First you have to convert that youtube video url into stream, you can do that using [YoutubeExplode plugin](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode).

```cs
var videoId = (string)parameters["videoId"];
var videoURL = $"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={videoId}";
var youtube = new YoutubeClient();

var streamManifest = await youtube.Videos.Streams.GetManifestAsync(videoId);
var streamInfo = streamManifest.GetMuxed().WithHighestVideoQuality();

if (streamInfo != null)
{
    // Get the actual stream
    var stream = await youtube.Videos.Streams.GetAsync(streamInfo);
    var source = streamInfo.Url;

   // Then use it with MediaElement
   mediaSource.Source = source; 
}
```

Comment: If you're passing the URL, you don't need the `stream`. But worth noting that the stream object returned by YoutubeExplode is quite involved so you will want to use that, if possible, over the URL, as it takes care of a lot of things.

Comment: Im not finding GetMuxed in xamrain forms  im using lattest version of the lib

Comment: streamManifest.GetMuxedStreams().GetWithHighestVideoQuality();